# Raphael SVG event similar Element.dblclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am using Raphael JS for creating an SVG web editor, it is designed for Iphone, and other touch enabled devices and also for desktop PCs. I am facing a difficulty in finding a similar event like Element.dblclick() to use with iphone ?
can anybody help me? 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

There are touch events available in Raphael

**Element.touchstart** - http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.touchstart